# Is our server & cdn ready for more active user?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, server, cloudflare

my client has an online shop and we upgraded our infrastructure for a cooperation on monday (16.11),
could anyone estimate if were rdy for more active user?

- WP + Woocommerce
- Managed Server (Intel® Xeon® E3-1231v3, 4 x 3,4 GHz, 32 GB DDR4 RAM)
- Cloudflare CDN (Business Plan)
- OnPage seo is good
- max. active user before: 150
- expected active user: ~500 or more
- [Latest Loadfocus stress test here](https://webdesign-bellotta.de/stackoverflow.pdf)

*sorry for my bad eng =/

Thanks & stay healthy

Comment: addition: max execution time is 20s & memory limit is set to 128MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with 4CPU x 3,4 GHz, 32 GB DDR4 RAM you are more than ready for that trafic :)